# Grow a pandas panel along major_axis with a stream of new data?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, containers, panel

My application has a stream of incoming data of the form

```
name, datetime, {x, y, z}
```

or in other words, I receive single rows of data, with columns `name, datetime, x, y, z`. I get bursts of data, every few minutes, some of which is new.

I want to store this data in a pandas `Panel`. The structure of this storage panel is such that

```
panel.items       - [name_1,name_2,...,name_n]
panel.major_axis  - [datetime1,datetime2,...datetime_m]
panel.minor_axis  - [x, y, z]
```

It seems `Panel` objects are not very resizable for efficiency reasons. However, it is not possible to know what `datetimes` the `major_axis` will contain. It's even possible I receive a new `datetime` between previous ones.

I *do* know what `items` and `minor_axis` will contain (although I would be happier without this restriction).

I want to grow this storage panel as necessary. Speed is not an issue. Open to other using other container types convertible to a panel. Any suggestions?

---

**Ideas**

I am playing with temporarily storing the data into a dict-of-dict-of-dict structure, perhaps converting to a `Panel` after each burst, and then somehow combining it with the storage `Panel`.

`old_panel = old_panel.set_value(item, major, minor, value)` didn't seem to work like it should in the documentation, but also it seems so drastic to create a new panel every time (since the old one could be huge).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say scrap the panel for now and use a dataframe with a `pd.Multi-Index`

***sample data***
assuming `'x', 'y', 'z'` come in a tuple

```
data = [
    ['a', pd.Timestamp('2016-03-31'), (1, 2, 3)],
    ['a', pd.Timestamp('2016-04-30'), (1, 2, 3)],
    ['a', pd.Timestamp('2016-07-31'), (1, 2, 3)],
    ['a', pd.Timestamp('2016-05-31'), (1, 2, 3)],
    ['b', pd.Timestamp('2016-03-31'), (1, 2, 3)],
    ['b', pd.Timestamp('2016-05-31'), (1, 2, 3)],
    ['b', pd.Timestamp('2016-08-31'), (1, 2, 3)],
]
```

---

Build empty dataframe

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list('abc'), list('xyz')])
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=mux)
```

Iterate over data to simulate streaming data

```
for d in data:
    df.loc[d[1], pd.IndexSlice[d[0], list('xyz')]] = d[2]
```

---

***results***

```
print(df)

              a              b              c          
              x    y    z    x    y    z    x    y    z
2016-03-31    1    2    3    1    2    3  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-04-30    1    2    3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-07-31    1    2    3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-05-31    1    2    3    1    2    3  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-08-31  NaN  NaN  NaN    1    2    3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

You could always get the panel like this

```
df.stack().to_panel()

<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 3 (items) x 5 (major_axis) x 3 (minor_axis)
Items axis: a to c
Major_axis axis: 2016-03-31 00:00:00 to 2016-08-31 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: x to z
```

Comment: Works like a charm. The only thing I couldn't get to work was that in real life, my columns are not `['x','y','z']` but actually `my_col = ['high','low','close',....]` and using your code I could not use `df.loc[d[1], pd.IndexSlice[d[0],my_col]] = d[2]'` without throwing an error about the index being "fully lexsorted". Instead, I just threw away the "`,my_col`" part, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Tips for anyone trying to follow this approach: Make sure either to `.sort_values()` your `mux` or `.sort_values(axis=1)` on your dataframe because `IndexSlice` only works on a fully sorted axis. Also, be aware that adding rows in the above fashion will add them to the bottom regardless of chronological order, so call `.sort_values(axis=0, inplace=True)` if you need to sort the chronological index.